# Retrieving count of two columns having null values

Tags: sql

I have two columns in a table and I want a SINGLE query for this: I need the count of null values of each column. It is said that in a row if first column contains null value the second may contain or may not contain and Viceversa.

I am a beginner and am not having much idea about this to try it out

Comment: Which DBS are you using ? And what did you do ?

Comment: I wrote a separate queries for both conditions....bout I want in single queriea

Answer (score 1):

```
Select column1,
(Select count(*) From table Where column = null),
(Select count(*) From table Where column2 = null)
From table
```

If you want to do this in a single query, use sub-queries

Comment: Could you please explain this query

Comment: @saikrishna Sure, the first part - `select column` is *not* necessary. the next two are called sub-queries. A sub-query can work as its own query, and in this case the subquery will return the count of how many null items exist in the table